# Cannot convert return expression of type

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently struggling figuring out this problem. 
I have a dynamic framework which implements a Network API f.e lets use GitHub.

The dynamic framework implements a class named `GitHub` with the following method:

```
func repos() -> Promise<[Repository]>
```

The promise implementation is my own implementation which is shared with the app target and the dynamic framework target.

In the app target I define a protocol `Client`.

```
protocol Client {
    func repositories() -> Promise<[RepositoryWrapper]>
}
```

Then I let `GitHub` extend from this protocol in order to transform `[Repository]` to `[RepositoryWrapper]`.

```
extension GitHub: Client {
    func repos() -> Promise<[RepositoryWrapper]> {
        return repositories().map({ repos in
            repos.map { transform(repository: $0) }
        })
    }

    private func transform(repository: Repository) -> RepositoryWrapper {
        return RepositoryWrapper(id: repository.id, nameWithOwner: repository.nameWithOwner)
    }

}
```

However I am currently getting the error message:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'Promise<[RepositoryWrapper]>' to return type 'Promise<[RepositoryWrapper]>'
```

I am not quite sure how to solve this since the error message states that the types are the same. If the implementation of map on Promise is needed I am happy to extend this question.

Comment: Seems like you have other issues and compiler is just throwing non-sense. If you comment this method(`repos()`) does your code compiles successfully?

Comment: Yes if I comment the current implementation and replace the return with an empty promise the code compiles just fine.

Comment: Hmm. Could you then share the minimum code to reproduce the issue? Also try renaming `repos()` method in `GitHub` extension to `reposWrapper()`.

Comment: Sure I'll try to fire up the playground.

Comment: Hm my playground works. So it looks like this is a project setup issue. Seems like that my setup with the dynamic framework target and app target is not correctly. I'll try to debug this. However the above error seems to be a symptom of this. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue was that I used the Promise implementation by sharing it to both targets. Once I added it only to the framework target and made it public to use it in the app the above implementation started working.